# Find out subdomain using Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Sorry if this is too little of a challenge to be suited as a stack overflow question, but I'm kind of new to Regular Expressions.

My question is, what is the regular expression that returns the string "token" for all the examples bellow?

- token.domain.com
- token.domain.com/
- token.domain.com/index.php
- token.domain.com/folder/index.php
- token.domain.com/folder/subfolder
- token.domain.com/folder/subfolder/index.php
- **(added after edit)**
- domain.com
- domain.com/

Im trying to use inside an preg_replace function in order to find out the subdomain of the current page from the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable.

Thank you in advance,
titel

**Edit note:** Sorry chaos and sebnow , I edited my question, what I initially meant, but forgot to write, was that this would work without any subdomain at all - case in which it would return an empty sting or NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/^(?:([^\.]+)\.)?domain\.com$/', '\1', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
```

**Edit:** What does the following output for you:

```
<?php
    echo preg_replace('/^(?:([^\.]+)\.)?domain\.com$/', '\1', "sean.domain.com") . "<br />";
    echo preg_replace('/^(?:([^\.]+)\.)?domain\.com$/', '\1', "titel.domain.com") . "<br />";
    echo preg_replace('/^(?:([^\.]+)\.)?domain\.com$/', '\1', "domain.com") . "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: :( unfortunately the solution you described does not seem to work in my case

Comment: It does work now, I guess I misspelled something while I was passing the script to use my actual domain. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Constantin TOVISI

Answer (score 3):

The following regex would capture any string before a full stop (the subdomain) and the rest of the domain:

```
^([^.]+)\..*$
```

I don't see the need for regex to do this though. It would be much easier to split by the full stop and get the first element:

```
list($subdomain, $rest) = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use preg_replace(), then:

```
preg_replace('/\..*/', '', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('@^([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$@',$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], $matches);
```