# subdomain extract without regex with php

Tags: php

**is there a great way to extract subdomain with php without regex ?**

why without regex ?

there are a lot of topic about this, one if them is [Find out subdomain using Regular Expression in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535336/find-out-subdomain-using-regular-expression-in-php)

> the internet says it consumes memory a
>   lot, if there is any consideration or
>   you think better use regex ( maybe we
>   use a lot of function to get this
>   solution ) please comment below too.

example

```
static.x.com = 'static'
helloworld.x.com = 'helloworld'
b.static.ak.x.com = 'b.static.ak'
x.com = ''
www.x.com = ''
```

Thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: A regex in a case like this is trivial and by no means does it consume "memory a lot"

Comment: Is this really a safe/wise data collection method? for instance: www.bbc.co.uk

Comment: horatio umm yes, thats why, im asking this. i my self use a .co.id :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/explode ?

Just split them on the dot? And do some functions?

Or if the last part (x.com) is the same everytime, do a substring on the hostname, stripping of the last part.

The only exception you'll have to make in your handling is the www.x.com (which technically is a subdomain).

```
$hostname = '....';
$baseHost = 'x.com';

$subdomain = substr($hostname, 0, -strlen($baseHost));
if ($subdomain === 'www') {
  $subdomain = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoever told you that regexes "consume a lot" was an idiot. Simple regexes are not very cpu/memory-consuming.

However, for your purpose a regex is clearly overkill. You can `explode()` the string and then take as many elements from the array as you need. However, your last example is really bad. `www` is a perfectly valid subdomain.

Comment: +1 for calling that guy an idiot. A stupid and ignorant idiot.

Comment: wew thank you. everyone says that, or maybe there are a lot of cargo cult programmer in the world of www.

Comment: regexes CAN potentially use a lot of memory, but it depends on the pattern. To say they 'always' consume is definitely wrong. But it's also wrong to say they don't ever.

Answer (score 1):

You can first use parse_url http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php
and than explode with . as delimiter on the host http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

I would not say it is quicker (just test it), but maybe this solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSubdomain($host) {
    return implode('.', explode('.', $host, -2));
}
```

[`explode`](http://php.net/explode) splits the string on the dot and drops the last two elements. Then [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) combines these pieces again using the dot as separator.

Comment: @Adam: `www.bbc` is the subdomain in this case. Technically speaking, this is correct.