# Combining php function

Tags: php, function

This code works:

```
    $host = parse_url('http://www.cc.joomla.mywebsite.net/paypal.com/myspace.com/login.php', PHP_URL_HOST);

    $host_names = explode(".", $host);
    print_r($host_names);
    echo "<br>";
    $l = array_slice($host_names, -3);
    print_r($l);
    echo "<br>";

    $subdomain = implode(".", $l);
    echo $subdomain;    //final result
```

Is it possible to combine function in one line for example like this:

```
$subdomain = implode(array_slice (explode(".", $host)($host_names, -3)(".", $l);
```

The example above does not worked. I think I have seen it before where you can combine function.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You either have a hard time to formulate the *expression* syntactically correct *or* you just want to learn about writing your own http://php.net/language.functions <- I suggest you the latter. Because the first one is self-mockery and so you should do it your own to make you really proud. Having others write you one-liners is considered cheating in this browser game here. :D

Comment: Also, what is the goal of your function? Just to get the subdomain?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535336/find-out-subdomain-using-regular-expression-in-php, anyway :)

Comment: @hakre -I don't know how to combine function. deceze below explains nicely what I need.

Comment: @Fabien - yes to get the subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just substitute each variable with the expression that you assign to it:

```
$host_names = explode(".", $host);
$l = array_slice($host_names, -3);
```

becomes

```
$l = array_slice(explode(".", $host), -3);
```

Then

```
$l = array_slice(explode(".", $host), -3);
$subdomain = implode(".", $l);
```

becomes

```
$subdomain = implode(".", array_slice(explode(".", $host), -3));
```

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation. exactly the information I need.

Comment: hmm, this does not do the print_r's in question and does not echo the br's. I wonder how it matches the requirement in the question ... . ;)

Comment: the `print_r` and `<br>` is just for example. I just need to know how to combine multiple function in single line.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing all your 3 lines into one, but it should be in this format to combine output of 1 function into another.

```
$subdomain = implode(".",array_slice(explode(".", $host), -3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain funktions "like" that. But if you don't take care they care getting unreadably. Like yours and then errors are difficult to be found:

```
implode(array_slice (explode(".", $host)/* this is not a valid function call */($host_names, -3) /* same here*/ (".", $l);
```

There are so many function calls that you really don't want them all into one line. Its unreadable.

You probably want to write your own function.:
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
$host_names = implode(".", array_slice(explode(".", $host), -3));
```